# How do I "group by" in django using a filter on a ForeignKey

Tags: django

I am trying to filter members based on name and return the members and affiliated companies.  My models are:

```
class Member( models.Model ):
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length=40, blank=False, null=False )
    last_name = models.CharField( max_length=40, blank=False, null=False )

 class Affiliation( models.Model ):

    member = models.ForeignKey( Member )
    company = models.ForeignKey( Company )
    date_entered = models.DateField( null = False, blank = False )
    date_exited = models.DateField( null = True, blank = True )

 class Company( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 100 )
```

and then I want to search on Member, find everyone whose name matches some string and show them all along with their company affiliations.  So for searches I could do:

```
def member_search(request):

    member_list = Member.objects.filter(
                Q( first_name__icontains=request.POST['q'].lower() )  |
                Q( last_name__icontains=request.POST['q'].lower() ) )

    return render_to_response('member/member_list.html', {'member_list': member_list } )
```

or

```
def member_search2(request):

    affiliation_list = Affiliation.objects.filter(
                Q( member__first_name__icontains=request.POST['q'].lower() )  |
                Q( member__last_name__icontains=request.POST['q'].lower() ) )

    return render_to_response('member/member_list2.html', {'affiliation_list': affiliation_list } )
```

In the first case the template would be something like:

```
<ul>
    {% for member in member_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="/member/{{ member.pk }}">view</a>

            <a href="/member/{{ member.pk }}/update">edit</a>

            {{ member.first_name }} {{ member.last_name }}

            {{ member.affiliation.all ??? }}

        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but I don't see how to reverse back through the Affiliation ForeignKey. I suspect my filter is going to have to change but I don't understand how.

and in the second case it would be something like:

```
<ul>
    {% for affiliation in affiliation_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="/member/{{ affiliation.member.pk }}">view</a>

            <a href="/member/{{ affiliation.member.pk }}/update">edit</a>

            {{ affiliation.member.first_name }} {{ affiliation.member.last_name }}

            {{ affiliation.member.company.name }}

        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

but then I get multiple lines for a member if they are affiliated with multiple companies.  I looked at the aggregate but it is not clear in this case as I want to list the companies too.

What I want in the end is:

```
member 1 ( company 1 [entry date], company 2 [entry date] )
member 2 ( company 1 [entry date] )
member 3 ( company 2 [entry date] )
```

This is very likely a duplicate of another question but I haven't found that question :-).  It seems like a common thing someone would want to do.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more I think I want to lean toward the second method as I would really like to have `member 1 (company 1 [entry date])` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can try:

For 1st, you can get affiliations with `affiliation_set`

```
{{ member.affiliation_set.all }}
```

---

For 2nd, you need to get dict of values that you want to show. After that you can use [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template filter tag to group the dict appropriately. Sample code

```
def member_search2(request):

    affiliation_list = Affiliation.objects.filter( #your filter ...)
                      .values('member__first_name', 'member__last_name', 
                              'company__name', `date_entered') 
      ....
```

And in template

```
{% regroup affiliation_list|dictsort:"member__first_name" by 
       member__first_name as aflist %}

<ul>
{% for af in aflist %}
    <li> {{af.grouper }}
    <ul>
     {%for m in af.list %}
        <li> {{m.company__name}} : {{m.date_entered}} </li>
     {%endfor%}
    </ul>
    </li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>
```

Comment: as an aside, how would I sort by last_name,first_name?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question... I would like to group by member__id as people might have the same name and I would like to sort by lastname,firstname. I tried `{% regroup affiliation_list|dictsort:"member__last_name" by member__id as aflist %}` but the member id was listed in the `{{af.grouper }}`.  So how would I put their name there and have it sorted by `member__last_name,member__first_name`?

Answer (score 1):

The first method is by far the simpler, and still gets you your desired output - as Rohan shows, you just need to use `{{ member.affiliation_set.all }}` for each member.

However, this will be very expensive as each call is another database query, and the hop from affiliation to company is yet another database call each time. You can make this a lot cheaper by using `prefetch_related` in your initial database call:

```
member_list = Member.objects.prefetch_related('affiliation__toppings').filter(...)
```

Another thing to think about, although it wouldn't help necessarily with your current scenario, is that the relationship between Member and Company is actually a many-to-many, with Affiliation as the through table. You can add extra functionality without changing your database structure by declaring that explicitly:

```
class Member( models.Model ):
    ...
    companies = models.ManyToManyField('Company', through='Affiliation')
```

and now member objects can do `member.companies.all()` to get all their companies directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Appreciated.

Comment: This last thing is a logical change, correct?  (hence the comment about not changing the database structure?)  It would actually be very helpful.